# What is a straight forward approach to matching and enumerating the results of a quiz using Python

Tags: python

In the code below (which shows all my neophyteness in Python), I took the books of the KJV Bible and put them in logical order via a list and dictionary. I then used a random method to display 5 random books to a user along with the position of the each book in a random list for the user to match (something for me to better learn the books of the Bible). My difficulty is figuring out how to go about saving the results and tallying up the number correct/wrong. I also would like to give the user an option to choose the number of questions like 10, 15, 20, or 30 .... Can someone give me direction on this? Thanks!

```
import random
import os

if __name__=='__main__':

    books=['Genesis', 'Exodus', 'Leviticus', 'Numbers', 'Deuteronomy', 'Joshua',
       'Judges', 'Ruth', 'I Samuel', 'II Samuel', 'I Kings', 'II Kings',
       'I Chronicles', 'II Chronicles', 'Ezra', 'Nehemiah', 'Esther', 'Job', 'Psalms',
       'Proverbs', 'Ecclesiastes', 'Song of Solomon', 'Isaiah', 'Jeremiah',
       'Lamentations', 'Ezekiel', 'Daniel', 'Hosea', 'Joel', 'Amos', 'Obadiah',
       'Jonah', 'Micah', 'Nahum', 'Habakkuk', 'Zephaniah', 'Haggai', 'Zechariah',
       'Malachi', 'Matthew', 'Mark', 'Luke', 'John', 'Acts', 'Romans', 'I Corinthians',
       'II Corinthians', 'Galatians', 'Ephesians', 'Philippians',
       'Colossians', 'I Thessalonians', 'II Thessalonians', 'I Timothy', 'II Timothy',
       'Titus', 'Philemon', 'Hebrews', 'James', 'I Peter', 'II Peter', 'I John',
       'II John', 'III John', 'Jude', 'Revelation']

Title = "{0:^78}".format("Welcome to the Bible book quiz!\n\n")



seleCtion = raw_input(" The Bible has a number of " + str(len(books)) + " books.\n Select Next to see them below:\n" + "{0:^78}".format("[1]Next    [2]Exit\n") )

if seleCtion == '1':

 #This section displays the books of the Bible and their indexes.
    count = 1
    indexMap = {}

    for i, bname in enumerate(books):
        print '\n{0:3d}. {1}'.format(count, bname)
        indexMap[count] = i
        count +=1


elif seleCtion == '2':
    print Title
    print "\n Let's start the quiz:\n\n\n"


else:
    print 'You must select 1 or 2'



mydict_book = {'Genesis':1, 'Exodus':2, 'Leviticus':3, 'Numbers':4, 'Deuteronomy':5, 'Joshua':6,
       'Judges':7, 'Ruth':8, 'I Samuel':9, 'II Samuel':10, 'I Kings':11, 'II Kings':12,
       'I Chronicles':13, 'II Chronicles':14, 'Ezra':15, 'Nehemiah':16, 'Esther':17, 'Job':18, 'Psalms':19,
       'Proverbs':20, 'Ecclesiastes':21, 'Song of Solomon':22, 'Isaiah':23, 'Jeremiah':24,
       'Lamentations':25, 'Ezekiel':26, 'Daniel':27, 'Hosea':28, 'Joel':29, 'Amos':30, 'Obadiah':31,
       'Jonah':32, 'Micah':33, 'Nahum':34, 'Habakkuk':35, 'Zephaniah':36, 'Haggai':37, 'Zechariah':38,
       'Malachi':39, 'Matthew':40, 'Mark':41, 'Luke':42, 'John':43, 'Acts':44, 'Romans':45, 'I Corinthians':46,
       'II Corinthians':47, 'Galatians':48, 'Ephesians':49, 'Philippians':50,
       'Colossians':51, 'I Thessalonians':52, 'II Thessalonians':53, 'I Timothy':54, 'II Timothy':55,
       'Titus':56, 'Philemon':57, 'Hebrews':58, 'James':59, 'I Peter':60, 'II Peter':61, 'I John':62,
       'II John':63, 'III John':64, 'Jude':65, 'Revelation':66}    



#new_dict = dict.fromkeys(books, counter)
#print new_dict




while 1:
    try:
        #This section starts the random book selection index match
        user_sel = []


        print '\n\n\n Here are the first 5 books in the quiz: \n'    
        sampler =random.sample(books, 5)
        first = str(sampler[0])
        second = str(sampler[1])
        third = str(sampler[2])
        fourth = str(sampler[3])
        fifth = str(sampler[4])
        user_sel = mydict_book[first], mydict_book[second], mydict_book[third], mydict_book[fourth], mydict_book[fifth]
        num_sampler = random.sample(user_sel, 5)

        print sampler
        print '\nMatch the correct numeric position below:'
        print '\n', num_sampler

        samp1 = int(raw_input('\nWhich number is ' + sampler[0] +': '))
        samp2 = int(raw_input('Which number is ' + sampler[1] +': '))
        samp3 = int(raw_input('Which number is ' + sampler[2] +': '))
        samp4 = int(raw_input('Which number is ' + sampler[3] +': '))
        samp5 = int(raw_input('Which number is ' + sampler[4] +': '))


        # taking the the users answer and finding the resultant book
        # need to put an if statement condition for !< 1 and ! < 66
        answer1=books[samp1-1]
        answer2=books[samp2-1]
        answer3=books[samp3-1]
        answer4=books[samp4-1]
        answer5=books[samp5-1]

        # taking the book and finding the numeric value associated with it


        right1 = mydict_book[answer1]
        right2 = mydict_book[answer2]
        right3 = mydict_book[answer3]
        right4 = mydict_book[answer4]
        right5 = mydict_book[answer5]



        #display what my answers yield
        print '\nYour Answers yield:\n'
        print "1. " + str(answer1) 
        print "2. " + str(answer2) 
        print "3. " + str(answer3)
        print "4. " + str(answer4)
        print "5. " + str(answer5)

        #takes the random books converts them to strings
        first = str(sampler[0])
        second = str(sampler[1])
        third = str(sampler[2])
        fourth = str(sampler[3])
        fifth = str(sampler[4])

        # print the numeric value and string value of the correct answers.         
        print "\nThe Correct Answers are:\n"
        print sampler[0] + " - " , mydict_book[first], tstmnt
        print sampler[1] + " - " , mydict_book[second], tstmnt
        print sampler[2] + " - " , mydict_book[third], tstmnt
        print sampler[3] + " - " , mydict_book[fourth], tstmnt
        print sampler[4] + " - " , mydict_book[fifth], tstmnt


        continue


    except ValueError:
        break
```

Comment: "My difficulty is figuring out how to go about saving the results and tallying up the number correct/wrong."?  Are you asking how to do `right = right + 1`?  And `wrong = wrong + 1`?

Comment: I imagine so ... along with another app I'm working on, I got frustrated and couldn't concentrate. I will attempt that approach.

Comment: "I imagine so"?  It's not clear what you need to know.

Comment: save the responses in a list, make another list with the correct order and then compare both lists with something like `[r == a for r, a in zip(resp, order)]` Or you could just count oks and wrongs after every input

Comment: @user706808: You might want to post this code on [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/] (Code Review).  You really need help learning to program.

Comment: Well, I would like to give the user an option to choose how many questions he/she would like to answer, and take the user's answers and determine the amount wrong or right and display the result at the end of the quiz.

Comment: " I would like to give the user an option to choose"  Are you asking how to prompt the user for a number?  You have numerous examples of that already in your program.  What is the real question here?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a variable named `selection`, so why the weird capitalization?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel I think I was initially using a var selection some where in the same scope, hence the var seleCtion. When I deleted some lines, I just never changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random
import os

if __name__=='__main__':

    books = ['Genesis', 'Exodus', 'Leviticus', 'Numbers', 'Deuteronomy',
             'Joshua', 'Judges', 'Ruth', 'I Samuel', 'II Samuel', 'I Kings',
             'II Kings', 'I Chronicles', 'II Chronicles', 'Ezra', 'Nehemiah',
             'Esther', 'Job', 'Psalms', 'Proverbs', 'Ecclesiastes',
             'Song of Solomon', 'Isaiah', 'Jeremiah', 'Lamentations',
             'Ezekiel', 'Daniel', 'Hosea', 'Joel', 'Amos', 'Obadiah', 'Jonah',
             'Micah', 'Nahum', 'Habakkuk', 'Zephaniah', 'Haggai', 'Zechariah',
             'Malachi', 'Matthew', 'Mark', 'Luke', 'John', 'Acts', 'Romans',
             'I Corinthians', 'II Corinthians', 'Galatians', 'Ephesians',
             'Philippians', 'Colossians', 'I Thessalonians',
             'II Thessalonians', 'I Timothy', 'II Timothy', 'Titus',
             'Philemon', 'Hebrews', 'James', 'I Peter', 'II Peter', 'I John',
             'II John', 'III John', 'Jude', 'Revelation']

    mydict_book = dict((bname,i) for i,bname in enumerate(books,start=1))


while True:
    seleCtion = raw_input(" The Bible has a number of %s books.\n" % len(books) \
                          + "Select Next to see them below:\n" \
                          + "{0:^78}".format("[1]Print All books   [2]Start Quiz\n"))

    if seleCtion == '1':
        print '\n'.join('{0:3d}. {1}'.format(i, bname) for i,bname in mydict_book.iteritems())
        break

    elif seleCtion == '2':
        print "{0:^78}\nLet's start the quiz:\n\n".format("Welcome to the Bible book quiz!\n\n")
        break

    else:
        print 'You must select 1 or 2'


while 1:
    try:
        num_ques = int(raw_input('\nEnter the number of questions you wanna be asked: '))
        sampler  = random.sample(books, num_ques)
        if not sampler:  exit(0)

        num_sampler = map(lambda bname: mydict_book[bname] , sampler)
        print 'num_sampler==',num_sampler

        print ('\n\n\nHere are the first %s books in the quiz: \n%s'
               '\nMatch the correct numeric positions below :\n%s') \
               % (num_ques,  str(sampler)[1:-1],  str(random.sample(num_sampler,num_ques))[1:-1])

        samp = [ int(raw_input('\nWhich number is %s : ' % books[i-1])) for i in num_sampler ]

        your = zip(samp,sampler)
        your.sort()
        print '\nYour Answers yield:\n' + '\n'.join('%2s. %s' % (n,bk) for n,bk in your)

        correct = zip(num_sampler,sampler)
        correct.sort()
        print "\nThe Correct Answers are:\n" + '\n'.join('%2s - %s' % (n,bk) for n,bk in correct) 

        continue


    except ValueError:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing that might help you is to use lists, list comprehension statements and loops, e.g.

```
q_count = int(raw_input('How many questions per quiz?'))

quiz_items = [str(sampler(x)) for x in range(q_count)]
user_sel = [mydict_book[x] for x in quiz_items]
```

...

```
answers = []
for i in range(q_count):
    next_answer = int(raw_input('\nWhich number is ' + sampler[i] +': '))
    answers.append(books[next_answer-1])
```

...

Answer (score 1):

"My difficulty is figuring out how to go about saving the results and tallying up the number correct/wrong. I also would like to give the user an option to choose the number of questions like 10, 15, 20, or 30 .... Can someone give me direction on this?:

I guess you can do something like:

```
right = 0
wrong = 0
...

numSamp = raw_input("Enter the amount of samples: ")

for i in xrange(numSamp):
    answer = int(raw_input('\nWhich number is ' + sampler[i] +': '))

    if book[answer-1] == sampler[i]:
       right=right+1
    else:
        wrong=wrong+1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete code, execute it and see if you like it. I've erased some of your lines.

```
import random
import os

if __name__=='__main__':

    books=['Genesis', 'Exodus', 'Leviticus', 'Numbers', 'Deuteronomy', 'Joshua',
       'Judges', 'Ruth', 'I Samuel', 'II Samuel', 'I Kings', 'II Kings',
       'I Chronicles', 'II Chronicles', 'Ezra', 'Nehemiah', 'Esther', 'Job', 'Psalms',
       'Proverbs', 'Ecclesiastes', 'Song of Solomon', 'Isaiah', 'Jeremiah',
       'Lamentations', 'Ezekiel', 'Daniel', 'Hosea', 'Joel', 'Amos', 'Obadiah',
       'Jonah', 'Micah', 'Nahum', 'Habakkuk', 'Zephaniah', 'Haggai', 'Zechariah',
       'Malachi', 'Matthew', 'Mark', 'Luke', 'John', 'Acts', 'Romans', 'I Corinthians',
       'II Corinthians', 'Galatians', 'Ephesians', 'Philippians',
       'Colossians', 'I Thessalonians', 'II Thessalonians', 'I Timothy', 'II Timothy',
       'Titus', 'Philemon', 'Hebrews', 'James', 'I Peter', 'II Peter', 'I John',
       'II John', 'III John', 'Jude', 'Revelation']

Title = "{0:^78}".format("Welcome to the Bible book quiz!\n\n")



seleCtion = raw_input(" The Bible has a number of " + str(len(books)) + " books.\n Select Next to see them below:\n" + "{0:^78}".format("[1]Print All books   [2]Start Quiz\n") )

if seleCtion == '1':

 #This section displays the books of the Bible and their indexes.
    count = 1
    indexMap = {}

    for i, bname in enumerate(books):
        print '\n{0:3d}. {1}'.format(count, bname)
        indexMap[count] = i
        count +=1


elif seleCtion == '2':
    print Title
    print "\n Let's start the quiz:\n\n\n"


else:
    print 'You must select 1 or 2'



mydict_book = {'Genesis':1, 'Exodus':2, 'Leviticus':3, 'Numbers':4, 'Deuteronomy':5, 'Joshua':6,
       'Judges':7, 'Ruth':8, 'I Samuel':9, 'II Samuel':10, 'I Kings':11, 'II Kings':12,
       'I Chronicles':13, 'II Chronicles':14, 'Ezra':15, 'Nehemiah':16, 'Esther':17, 'Job':18, 'Psalms':19,
       'Proverbs':20, 'Ecclesiastes':21, 'Song of Solomon':22, 'Isaiah':23, 'Jeremiah':24,
       'Lamentations':25, 'Ezekiel':26, 'Daniel':27, 'Hosea':28, 'Joel':29, 'Amos':30, 'Obadiah':31,
       'Jonah':32, 'Micah':33, 'Nahum':34, 'Habakkuk':35, 'Zephaniah':36, 'Haggai':37, 'Zechariah':38,
       'Malachi':39, 'Matthew':40, 'Mark':41, 'Luke':42, 'John':43, 'Acts':44, 'Romans':45, 'I Corinthians':46,
       'II Corinthians':47, 'Galatians':48, 'Ephesians':49, 'Philippians':50,
       'Colossians':51, 'I Thessalonians':52, 'II Thessalonians':53, 'I Timothy':54, 'II Timothy':55,
       'Titus':56, 'Philemon':57, 'Hebrews':58, 'James':59, 'I Peter':60, 'II Peter':61, 'I John':62,
       'II John':63, 'III John':64, 'Jude':65, 'Revelation':66}    



#new_dict = dict.fromkeys(books, counter)
#print new_dict




while 1:
    try:
        #This section starts the random book selection index match
        user_sel = []

        num_ques = int(raw_input('Enter the number of questions you wanna be asked: '))
        if num_ques == 0:
            exit(0)

        sampler =random.sample(books, num_ques)

        print '\n\n\n Here are the first ' + str(num_ques) + ' books in the quiz: \n'

        in_string = [] # this is your 'first', 'second', and so on...
        for i in range(num_ques):
            in_string.append( str(sampler[i]) )


        #user_sel = mydict_book[first], mydict_book[second], mydict_book[third], mydict_book[fourth], mydict_book[fifth]
        for i in range(num_ques):
            user_sel.append( mydict_book[in_string[i]] )

        num_sampler = random.sample(user_sel, num_ques)

        print sampler
        print '\nMatch the correct numeric position below:'
        print '\n', num_sampler

        #samp1 = int(raw_input('\nWhich number is ' + sampler[0] +': '))
        samp = []
        for i in range(num_ques):
            samp.append( int(raw_input('\nWhich number is ' + sampler[i] + ': ') ) )


        # taking the the users answer and finding the resultant book
        # need to put an if statement condition for !< 1 and ! < 66

        #answer1=books[samp1-1]
        answers = []
        for i in range(num_ques):
            answers.append( books[samp[i]-1] )

        # taking the book and finding the numeric value associated with it

        right = []
        for i in range(num_ques):
            right.append( mydict_book[ answers[i] ] )

        #right1 = mydict_book[answer1]



        #display what my answers yield
        print '\nYour Answers yield:\n'
        #print "1. " + str(answer1) 
        for i in range(num_ques):
            print str(i+1) + '. ' + str(answers[i]) 


        #takes the random books converts them to strings
        positions = []
        for i in range(num_ques):
            positions.append( str(sampler[i]) )

        #first = str(sampler[0])
        #second = str(sampler[1])
        #third = str(sampler[2])
        #fourth = str(sampler[3])
        #fifth = str(sampler[4])

        # print the numeric value and string value of the correct answers.         
        print "\nThe Correct Answers are:\n"

        for i in range(num_ques):
            print sampler[i] + ' - ', mydict_book[ positions[i] ]
        #print sampler[0] + " - " , mydict_book[first], tstmnt
        #print sampler[1] + " - " , mydict_book[second], tstmnt
        #print sampler[2] + " - " , mydict_book[third], tstmnt
        #print sampler[3] + " - " , mydict_book[fourth], tstmnt
        #print sampler[4] + " - " , mydict_book[fifth], tstmnt


        continue


    except ValueError:
        break
```